# MTB Features. What features are worth their weight

Tags: mountain-bike, hardtail

Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

I used to ride hardtails on trails a long time ago, 1995/96.

I'd like some advice on what to buy with my budget £765

Aluminium frame, good front shocks and deore+ drivetrain ideally.

But, it's been a while and I don't know what I'm talking about anymore.

I'm 5'9" - 75kg

I was looking at:

TREK X-CALIBER 7 ML

Voodoo Bizango 2022 (good reviews but hard to tell if the reviewer is in cahoots)

Anyway, any suggestions would be most welcome.

Have a fantastic week!

Comment: ["Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve."](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: MTB's come in MANY shapes and sizes compared to 1995/96 and mountain biking itself has evolved in line with the improved bikes.  Ideally rewrite the question telling us what style of riding you would like to do and ask what features to look for.  As it stands I voted to close for the reason above.

Comment: Okay, I'll rewrite it. Thanks

Comment: Good question.  I had a similar question about ten years ago to see what had changed after being away from MTB for 15 years. It’s the first step to reacquainting yourself with what has changed over time.  In general, triple chainrings are mostly out (except at the low end?). Double and single chainring MTBs rule everything above entry-level.  More gears on the cassette than ever.  Suspension changes are significant as well. Someone here has a much deeper answer than this, and will get you moving in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

All of them.  Weight loss vs features as a way to improve a MTB is overrated until you are spending really big dollars (if at all). Far more important things, like dropper posts, (better) suspension with more adjustment, tire choice for the type of terrain being ridden etc will improve the bikes speed and rideability far more than saving a few grams.

For instance, bigger brakes and better suspension that's heavier will allow the rider to corner faster, loosing less energy to slow down. This translates to not only going faster, but also using less effort to accelerate the bike.  A dropper post means the seat is set for optimal power on easy ground and instantly can be dropped for technical sections and jumps. Without a dropper, the seat high is going to be giving sub-optimal  power on easy ground, or make jumps and technical ground far more difficult (slowing and accelerating more, using more effort)

At the extreme - say putting on heavy down hill shock for riding easy trails, or putting on large disc 4 pot brakes when you only every ride on the road  are a weight penalty with no advantages.  This then leads into the need to focus on the right style bike for the riding you plan, not weight.

At the price point that weight saving measurably improves the bikes performance (e.g. time to complete a 500 vertical meter climb) you can buy an EBike for much less, and have just as much fun and go faster.

Comment: Ebike is not always more fun. Especially if you need to CARRY your bike.